# How to merge 3 different lists based on an common property?

Tags: c#

I develop an program on MVC Visual Studio. I have 3 different tables on database; teachers, students and parents. I used entity framework, i created models of these tables.'Joindate' is common property and there are 1000 persons in each table.
I need to find latest 10 persons in all tables. 
How can i do that?

```
public class teachers
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}


public class students
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public string Lesson { get; set; }


}

public class parents
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public string Job { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: By using LINQ..? Anyway, no data/code/expectations = unclear/no-problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *merge*? Do those instances within the lists have any common base-class? So what should the result-type of your list be? Have you even tried anything? We´re not doing your job, please provide some idea that you´ve already tried.

Comment: You are going to need to give use more info. Firstly , what have you tried? Secondly, what is the structure of each object?

Comment: Ever heard of inheritence ? Seems to me that all those classes have common fields (`ID, Name, JoinDate`) so they could all inherit a `person` class for example. Also consider changing your class names to singular as it is the structure for 1 item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some common class or interface for your three classes in ordere to store different instances into *one single* list. The list can have only *one single* type.

So define a base-interface for all of them:

```
interface IPerson
{
    DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    // more common properties or methods
}
public class Teacher : IPerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }    
}

public class Student : IPerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public string Lesson { get; set; }   
}

public class Parent : IPerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public string Job { get; set; }    
}
```

Now you can easily put instances that implement that interface into your list:

```
var myList = new List<IPerson> { aTeacher, aStudent, aParent };
```

Finally sort them based on the common property:

```
var result = myList.OrderBy(x => x.JoinDate);
```

As an aside notice that I changed the class-names into singular to identify a *single instance* of a `Teacher`. One `Teachers` makes no sense at all. Also use upper-case-names for them to follow naming-conventions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to create a class "Person" (or another name) which will specify that common property 'JoinDate', and all other common properties (Name, etc.). This class should also implement IComparable, in which you will implement the method "public int CompareTo(object obj)" like this:

```
public int CompareTo(Person p) {
    return this.JoinDate.CompareTo(p.JoinDate);
}
```

Your three classes (Teacher, Student, and Parent) should inherit from this class. Then you have to create an instance of List and add the three lists to it:

```
List<Person> rList = new List<Person>();
rList.AddRange(teachersList);
rList.AddRange(studentsList);
rList.AddRange(parentsList);
```

To sort the list you will only need to call:

```
rList.Sort();
```

And finally your list "rList" will be sorted.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The solution of HimBromBeere below is better

Comment: Thank you so much.